# Dynamically create query - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I manually write a query, it will be like

```
User.where("name LIKE(?) OR desc LIKE(?)",'abc','abc')
    .where("name LIKE(?) OR desc LIKE(?)",'123','123')
```

However, I need to dynamically generate that query.
I am getting data like

```
def generate_query(the_query)

   query,keywords = the_query

   # Here 
   # query = "name LIKE(?) OR desc LIKE(?)"
   # keywords = [['abc','abc'],['123','123']]

   keywords.each do |keyword|
       users = User.where(query,*keyword) <-- not sure how to dynamically add more 'where' conditions.    
    end

end
```

I am using Rails 5. Hope it is clear. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
q = User.where(a)
        .where(b)
        .where(c)
```

is equivalent to:

```
q = User
q = q.where(a)
q = q.where(b)
q = q.where(c)
```

So you could write:

```
users = User
keywords.each do |keyword|
  users = users.where(query, *keyword)
end
```

But any time you see that sort of feedback pattern (i.e. apply an operation to the operation's result or `f(f( ... f(x)))`) you should start thinking about [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (AKA `Enumerable#reduce`):

```
users = keywords.inject(User) { |users, k| users.where(query, *k) }
```

That said, your `query` has two placeholders but `keywords` is just a flat array so you won't have enough values in:

```
users.where(query, *k)
```

to replace the placeholders. I think you'd be better off using a named placeholder here:

```
query    = 'name like :k or desc like :k'
keywords = %w[abc 123]
users    = keywords.inject(User) { |users, k| users.where(query, k: k) }
```

You'd probably also want to include some pattern matching for your `LIKE` so:

```
query = "name like '%' || :k || '%' or desc like '%' || :k || '%'"
users = keywords.inject(User) { |users, k| users.where(query, k: k)
```

where `||` is the standard SQL string concatenation operator (which AFAIK not all databases understand) and `%` in a LIKE pattern matches any sequence of characters. Or you could add the pattern matching in Ruby and avoid having to worry about the different ways that databases handle string concatenation:

```
query = 'name like :k or desc like :k'
users = keywords.inject(User) { |users, k| users.where(query, k: "%#{k}%")
```

---

Furthermore, this:

```
User.where("name LIKE(?) OR desc LIKE(?)",'abc','abc')
    .where("name LIKE(?) OR desc LIKE(?)",'123','123')
```

produces a `WHERE` clause like:

```
where (name like 'abc' or desc like 'abc')
  and (name like '123' or desc like '123')
```

so you're matching **all** the keywords, not **any** of them. This may or may not be your intent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My array example was wrong. I fixed that.

Comment: Okay, if `keywords` is an array-of-arrays then `where(query, *k)` will be fine. I'd still lean towards keyword placeholders to avoid the repetition. You'd also want to use `*k.map { |k| "%#{k}%" }` to add the pattern matching characters.